# Youtube App Scheme URL for iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, youtube

I have used two different scheme URL for iOS/Android. Its works fine in both devices.

But i can't understand why this different only in youtube scheme URL?

> **iOS** Youtube Scheme URL :
>
> ```
> youtube://the.youtube.video.url
> ```
>
> **Android** Youtube Scheme URL :
>
> ```
> vnd.youtube://the.youtube.video.url
> vnd.youtube://TTajGJ9nJLA**    (youtube:// can't work with this scheme )
> ```

Appreciate your inputs on how to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

From iOS7 onwards, vnd.youtube works just fine.